# Travis-ci/github integration links to wrong travis build (for same source branch)

Tags: github, travis-ci

Here is my workflow:

- Branch from master
- Commit and push the branch to github
- Create a PR (1) from the branch to master
- Quickly create and merge a PR (2) for the same branch to an integration branch for manual QA

When I do this, travis builds get fired for both PRs (the first to master, to second to a qa branch). The tests pass on the former and fail on the latter because the PR is already closed.

I am ok with that particular behavior, but I noticed that the first PR (1) gets marked as bad according to travis because the test failed on the other PR (2). When I follow the integration link on the PR (1) to the failed travis build, the build references the other PR (2) in the merge ref: +refs/pull/2/merge. Very specifically, it's the `continuous-integration/travis-ci/push` that is marked as errored. The `continuous-integration/travis-ci/pr` is ok.

If I go to the `Pull requests` tab within travis-ci, the expected statuses are presented: PR #1 passed, PR #2 errored.

Have I configured things wrong, or is this a bug in the integration where it's tagging the wrong PR with the build failure (perhaps because they happen to share a source branch)? My only recourse for the moment is to run another build for PR #1 so that the github Open PRs tab shows me and my coworkers the reassuring checkmark.

Comment: When you say "tagging the wrong PR with Build failure", do you mean the Build Status changes from passing to failing? 

Is this the issue that you have - because there is an issue with the Status Badge  - you can refer to it  here - https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8125